# Using pagination in Laravel when the eloquent call has been made elsewhere

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I am trying to use paginate in Laravel.  The problem I am having is that all the examples I am finding involve eloquent calls.  I do not have access to the eloquent calls (someone else's code).  Instead I have a return variable called $data.  Inside $data I have a list, I want to paginate that list.  I have tried `$data['lists']::paginate(10)`, but that does not work.  Is there a correct way to paginate when you only have the data from the eloquent call?

Comment: is your `$data`  a collection ?

Comment: @jaysingkar, yes it is

Comment: check my answer.. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `paginate` as a macro on the `Collection` facade. This way any instance of the `Collection` class can be paginated including values returned from the `collect()` helper.

To do this open your `AppServiceProvider` and add

```
Collection::macro('paginate', function( $perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page' ) {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage( $pageName );

            return new LengthAwarePaginator( $this->forPage( $page, $perPage ), $total ?: $this->count(), $perPage, $page, [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName,
            ]);
        });
```

to the boot method.

You can then call paginate on any `Collection` 
eg. `collect([1,2,3])->paginate(2);`
or `$data->paginate(5);` in your case

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own paginator instance:

```
$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($data, $total, $perPage);
// replace $total with total entries in your $data variable    
return view('my.view', ['files' => $paginator]);
```